# Youtube REST API v3 - include statistics for video in search query result

Tags: rest, youtube, youtube-api

I want to perform search queries using Youtube API v3.
What I need is to retrieve video ids and statistics for each video.
From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource) I can see that statistics is not returned for video items. If I try to ask for statistics using this query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?type=video&part=snippet,statistics&q=kittens&key={MY_KEY}
```

I receive an error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.part",
    "reason": "unknownPart",
    "message": "statistics",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "statistics"
 }
}
```

So I guess that I need to make two requests:

1. Perform actual search and retrieve list of video ids.
2. Make API request https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list to retrieve statistics for each video.

Or maybe I'm missing something and there's a way to get statistics for videos within one search query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the guide, they specify "the part names that you can include in the parameter value are id and snippet" when using https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search. (statistics is not an accepted value).

So I think that you have to make two requests as you say, at least that is what I'm doing. I couldn't find any other solution. I would be interested to know if there was a workaround...

Comment: Hi Tilly, do you mind sharing some code how you are achieving this task? Thanks!

Comment: Word Tilly, what this guy above me said!

Answer (score 3):

To avoid redundancy of data returned and not to use bandwidth with extra data, "video search data" and "video statistics" data are decoupled in API.
You are right about two calls.
In general, to get faster response, only use the "part" s in request that you will use in your application.

Comment: Ibrahim - seems like statistics would commonly be required to display search results. Look at any list of videos (related, search, etc) on YouTube.com - they all include at least author and view count. The amt. of data returned from statistics isn't that much... are you sure there's no way to get the information in a single request?

Comment: Same thoughs… They used to give it all. At this pace, v4 will require to pay for each calls

Comment: @ibrahim-ulukaya true story many developers will be disappointed when changing from v2 to v3. Why should anybody do two http requests to display search results. This even doesn't correspond to any use case google apps display search results. And where are the rtsp links?

Comment: Same here from 2016. Statistics are something commonly required and im being crazy with that API.... So sad